# Microsoft Excel unable to color the data entry red

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I was tring to color a certain number in Microsoft Excel red, but I am unable to do so. For whatever reason, whenever I tried to color it, it automatically return to black color

Edit: [image]
edit2: It seems that coloring still work in certain area but not in others.
edit3: Here is the Excel document:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15dNpTHjum8i9-r3pUDxyxp7D6ZWLSqbq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this file protected?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Have you selected "this entire sheet" in the conditional formatting rules dialog? Sometimes the drop-down says "this selection" when you first open it, which means there still might be a rule.  Another option is to see if there's any VBA in the file which might be changing the color. It would have something behind the specific sheet as a Worksheet_Change event

Comment: I have clicked clear all rules option and it doesn't change a thing:(

Comment: @FlexYourData I don't know about anything VBA. I have uploaded my Excel file onto Google Cloud and would you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a conditional formatting (条件格式) rule in place. Please check for any rules listed there.

[image]

Comment: See the edit: I don't remember putting any rules in place. the rules list is empty